# ComboBox selected value not getting translated

Tags: javafx, combobox, translation

My app should have several languages. English is by default. Problem is that if user will switch to different language, everything will be translated except for `ComboBox` selected value. This is how it looks:

[image]

Code behind `ComboBox` is:

```
ObservableList<Currency> currencyItem= CurrencyDA.getCurrencies();
currenciesComboBox.setItems(currencyItem);
Callback<ListView<Currency>, ListCell<Currency>> currencyFactory = lv -> new ListCell<Currency>(){
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Currency currency, boolean empty){
            super.updateItem(currency, empty);
            setText(empty ? "" : interfaceBundle.getString("currency_"+currency.getName()));
            }
        };
currenciesComboBox.setCellFactory(currencyFactory);
currenciesComboBox.setButtonCell(currencyFactory.call(null));
currenciesComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

How can I get selected value refreshed?

Comment: You should also note that your update item method is wrong. You should test if item is != null and if is not empty prior to setText to the cell otherwise set it to null. Pls refer to the example in the doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html)

> As the ComboBox internally renders content with a ListView, API exists in the ComboBox class to allow for a custom cell factory to be set. For more information on cell factories, refer to the Cell and ListCell classes. **It is important to note that if a cell factory is set on a ComboBox, cells will only be used in the ListView that shows when the ComboBox is clicked. If you also want to customize the rendering of the 'button' area of the ComboBox, you can set a custom ListCell instance in the button cell property**. One way of doing this is with the following code :

```
 //(note the use of setButtonCell): 

 Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>> cellFactory = ...;
 ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
 comboBox.setItems(items);
 comboBox.setButtonCell(cellFactory.call(null));
 comboBox.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
```

So the only thing you have to add is :

**`currenciesComboBox.setButtonCell(currencyFactory.call(null));`**

Comment: sorry, my bad, I updated question. Didn't notice that I missed a couple of lines T^T

Comment: I placed this line also into my `translate()` method and it is working) So I think this answer is correct